# How to map terminal service printer port to something like COMx?

Tags: terminal, service, printer

I'd like to state my environment configuration first as follows:

1. A Zebra label printer with serial port (RS232) (print script .bat uses serial port only)
2. A serial cable (RS232) suitable for the printer.
3. A RS232 to USB switch cable.
4. A PC installed ubuntu 12.04.3 x86.
5. A Hyper-V VM installed Windows 7 with SP1.

What I've tested and succeded:

1. on ubuntu, type "sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0", and the type "echo ~WC > /dev/ttyUSB0", and this will print a test page on the printer successfully.
2. in ubuntu printer configuration GUI, add the usb serial port as a printer, and print a test page in the GUI. Print successfully.
3. on ubuntu, use freerdp (a most famous open source RDP client) to connect to the VM with "/printer" argument, it will redirect the local printer to Windows VM.
4. In the Windows VM, I can see the redirected printer in "Devices and Printers", and I can print a test page successfully.

What I've tested but failed:

1. In the printer's "Port" settings, it uses "TS004" or "TS005", the name is not fixed, it changes randomly...
2. The users have many printer scripts (industry .bat) which use only "type xxx > COM1", I cannot ask them to change their scripts to "TSxxx". What's more, "TSxxx" changes.

My question:

1. Can I make the terminal service port name "TS004" fixed?
2. Can I map the terminal service port name to "COM1"？How to do that? (I tested "net use COM1 TS004" but it does not work)

Any hints are appreciated. Many thanks!~

Comment: The TS00x is something of a session identifier for that particular RDS session. It's going to be different (AFAIK) every time the user establishes a session. Try redirecting the COM port.